# How to get the first and last concatinated string of the selected item in the spinner?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I added an adapter in my spinner and this is the code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                itemList);
```

I added items in my itemlist through this:

```
itemList.add(p.getCourseId()+" "+p.getRoom()+" "+p.getSection());
```

The data inside my spinner display these:
"IT117P R210 A58", "IT200P R310 A57", "IT500 3400 A28"
So the data respectively is the: course, room, and section.
What i need to do is to get the course string(p.getCourseId()) and the section string(p.getSection()) only (excluding the room) when the user clicks the spinner item. After selecting the item it will pass the data on another class

here is my code that is on onCreate:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    course=mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
               //this i think will get all the string item 
              //in spinner not the course and section only:(
             //HOW to get the course and section? 

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            data = bw.getAttendanceFromDB(term, course,sections);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers = attendanceUse(data);
                                    addAttendance(attendanceusers);                     
                                }
                            });   
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
```

UPDATE: here is my whole code and i implemented the split function:

Courseprof.java

```
public class Courseprof extends Activity{
String data = "";
TableLayout tl;
TableRow tr;
Button btcourse;
int term=1;
String course="",sections="";
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spincourse);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.courses);
        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

        final BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker(Courseprof.this,"Courseprof");
        Bundle get=getIntent().getExtras();
        final int profid=get.getInt("id"); //kunin ni course from fragment
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = bw.getCourseFromDB(profid);
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Properties> courseusers = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(courseusers);                     
                    }

                });   
            }
        }).start();

        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            String splithis;
            String[] splited=mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().split(" ");
            course = splited[0];
            sections = splited[2];
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    data = bw.getAttendanceFromDB(term, course,sections);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers = attendanceUse(data);
                            addAttendance(attendanceusers);                     
                        }
                    });   
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return;
        }
    });
    }
    public ArrayList<Properties> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<Properties> courseusers = new ArrayList<Properties>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Properties user = new Properties();
                user.setRoom(json_data.getString("rooms_id")); //ipinasa dito
                user.setCourse(json_data.getString("course_id"));
                user.setSection(json_data.getString("sections_id"));
                courseusers.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return courseusers;
    }
    public ArrayList<Properties> attendanceUse(String result) {
        ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers = new ArrayList<Properties>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Properties user = new Properties();
                user.setStudentfname(json_data.getString("student_fname")); //ipinasa dito
                user.setStudentmname(json_data.getString("student_mname"));
                user.setStudentlname(json_data.getString("student_lname"));
                user.setStatdescript(json_data.getString("status_description"));
                attendanceusers.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return attendanceusers;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Properties> courseusers) {

        List<String> itemList=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Iterator i = courseusers.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Properties p = (Properties) i.next();
              itemList.add(p.getCourseId()+" "+p.getRoom()+" "+p.getSection());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                itemList);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    TextView label;
    void addHeaderAttendance(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText("Students");
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView place = new TextView(this);
        place.setText("Status");
        place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        place.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        place.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(place,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addAttendance(ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers) {
        addHeaderAttendance();

        for (Iterator i = attendanceusers.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Properties p = (Properties) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getStudentfname()+" "+p.getStudentlname()+" "+p.getStudentmname());

            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            TextView stats = new TextView(this);
            stats.setText(p.getStatdescript());
            stats.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            stats.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            stats.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(stats,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

             // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is the error :

```
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.navigationdrawerdemo/in.wptrafficanalyzer.navigationdrawerdemo.Courseprof}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3132)

11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)

11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)

11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)

11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2316)
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.navigationdrawerdemo.Courseprof.<init>(Courseprof.java:35)
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1096)
11-10 20:36:24.964: E/AndroidRuntime(10862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
```

Comment: you can try with splitting on spaces, but since thoses String instances can contain spaces ....

Comment: do you think the event is right?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the selected string with space, to get values.

```
String[] data = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().split(" ");
course = data[0];
section = data[2];
```

Comment: I did your code but i'm still having an error do you think the event for getting the items in spinner is right? And is that should be putted on onCreate?

Comment: 11-10 20:25:46.500: E/AndroidRuntime(10236): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: i think the event causes the error not your code sir :( should i show my whole code? :(

Comment: Initialize spinner in OnCreate after setContentView.

Comment: now there has no error.. but my public void run() inside the 
        public void onItemSelected doesnt displays the data :o this is my last question *cries* sorryyy

Comment: No issues.. Got now??

Comment: hmm my issue is it is not displaying the view or data inside  public void addAttendance(ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers) . It is working when im still if predefining the course and sections w/o getting the value of spinner.

Answer (score 0):

you may use split function

Example

```
course=mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String[] splited = course.split(" ");

String first = splited[0];
String second = splited[1];
String last = splited[2];
```

You may make spinner global object like

```
private Spinner mySpinner;
```

initialize spinner in onCreate() method after setContentView like

```
mySpinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spincourse);
```

Comment: I also did your code but i'm still having an error do you think the event for getting the items in spinner is right? And is that should be putted on onCreate?

Comment: here is my error sir:

11-10 20:25:46.500: E/AndroidRuntime(10236): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: @J.Doe may be it's spinner binding error update question with full code

Comment: I update sir my post, the updated is at the bottom part of my post. Sorry sir :(

Comment: @J.Doe you may need to put  findViewById  under OnCreate method

Comment: now there has no error.. but my public void run() inside the public void onItemSelected doesnt displays the data , im sorry for asking too much question, but im fixing my code as well

Answer (score 0):

You can split `String` based on white spaces.

```
String selectedCource = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String[] words = selectedCource.split("\\s");//splits the string based on whitespace 

String course = words[0];
String selection = words[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
String[] data = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().split(" ");
course = data[0];
section = data[data.length-1];
```